# Are finite unions of almost disjoint families closed under infinite intersections?

Tags: general-topology, set-theory

In this [paper](http://topology.nipissingu.ca/tp/reprints/v28/tp28210.pdf), Example 4.6, the following is stated:

Let $\mathfrak F$ be a (maximal) almost disjoint family of infinite subsets of
$\mathbb N$ (i.e., $A \cap B$ is finite for all distinct $A, B \in \mathfrak F$.

Define
$\mathfrak{C} := \{ D \cup \bigcup_{k=1}^{n} A_k: D \text{ is a finite subset of } \mathbb N, n \in \omega, A_1, \ldots, A_n \in \mathfrak{F} \} \cup \{\mathbb N\}$.

*Statement:* Then $\mathfrak{C}$ is the set of closed subsets of a topology on $\mathbb N$.

In the paper, the authors distinguish between $\mathbb N = \{1,2, \ldots \}$
and $\omega$.
But I think this doesn't make a difference.
Moreover, I believe that if the statement were true, then it would also be true for almost disjoint families, i.e., the "maximal" doesn't make a difference.

Of course, $\mathfrak C$ is closed under finite unions and, I'm pretty sure, also under finite intersections.

But I doubt, that is closed under arbitrary intersections.
I had a discussion with one of the authors, where he couldn't convince me that it is true, but neither I could convince him, that it's false.

I think, for a counter-example, one has to consider an appropriate family
$(D_i)_{i \in \mathbb N}$ of finite sets with number of elements strictly increasing, and for each $i \in \mathbb N$, $A_{1, i}, ... A_{k_i, i}$ be elements from the almost disjoint family, $(k_i)_{i \in \mathbb N}$ be strictly increasing as well.
In order to *prove* the statement,
in the end of the day, one has to represent
$ T := \bigcap_{i \in \mathbb N} (D_i \cup \bigcup_{k=1}^{n_k} A_{k,i})$
in the given form. Of course, w.l.o.g., T is infinite.
But I cannot imagine, how this would look like?

However, so far, I didn't manage to explicitly write down such a counter-example, which, of course, would be necessary.

Might be such a counter-example does work for specific almost disjoint families, only?
Or is the statement false for any infinte / uncountable / maximal almost disjoint family?

Note. 
If the statement were true for at least one almost disjoint family of, say, size $2^\omega$, it would already be helpful, since this can then be used to construct certain Noetherian topological spaces, see for instance the paper mentioned above.
But just one counter-example would already (at least partially) answer my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that $\mathfrak F$ is a **maximal** almost disjoint family of infinite subsets of $\mathbb N$, arbitrary intersections of closed sets are closed.

Suppose $S=\bigcap\mathfrak S$ where $\mathfrak S$ is a nonempty collection of closed sets. Plainly $\{A\in\mathfrak F:A\subseteq S\}$ is finite; say $\{A\in\mathfrak F:A\subseteq S\}=\{A_1,\dots,A_n\}$. So $S=D\cup(A_1\cup\cdots\cup A_n)$ where $D=S\setminus(A_1\cup\cdots\cup A_n)$. Now I just have to show that $D$ is finite. Assume for a contradiction that $D$ is infinite. Then, by the maximality of $\mathfrak F$, there is some $B\in\mathfrak F$ which has infinite intersection with $D$. It follows that $B\cap F$ is infinite for each $F\in\mathfrak S$. Since $F$ is closed and $B\in\mathfrak F$, it follows that $B\subseteq F$ for each $F\in\mathfrak S$, that is, $B\subseteq S$. But this is absurd since $B\notin\{A_1,\dots,A_n\}$.

**P.S.** The almost disjoint family $\mathfrak F$ doesn't have to be maximal.

Suppose $S=\bigcap\mathfrak S$ where $\mathfrak S$ is a nonempty collection of closed sets; I claim that $S$ is closed. Write $S=D\cup\bigcup\mathfrak F_0$ where $\mathfrak F_0=\{A\in\mathfrak F:A\subseteq S\}$ and $D=S\setminus\bigcup\mathfrak F_0$. Then $\mathfrak F_0$ is finite since $\mathfrak S\ne\varnothing$; I have to show that $D$ is finite. Assume for a contradiction that $D$ is infinite.

Choose a finite subcollection $\mathfrak T\subseteq\mathfrak S$ so that $\{A\in\mathfrak F:A\subseteq\bigcap\mathfrak T\}=\mathfrak F_0$; say $\mathfrak T=\{D_1\cup\bigcup\mathfrak F_1,\dots,D_n\cup\bigcup\mathfrak F_n\}$ where $D_1,\dots,D_n$ are finite subsets of $\mathbb N$ and $\mathfrak F_1,\dots,\mathfrak F_n$ are finite subcollections of $\mathfrak F$. Since $D\subseteq S\subseteq\bigcap\mathfrak T$, and since $D$ is infinite and $D_1\cup\cdots\cup D_n$ is finite, it follows that $D$ has infinite intersection with $(\bigcup\mathfrak F_1)\cap\cdots\cap(\bigcup\mathfrak F_n)$. By the pigeonhole principle, there are sets $A_1\in\mathfrak F_1,\dots,A_n\in\mathfrak F_n$ such that $D\cap A_1\cap\cdots\cap A_n$ is infinite. Since the sets $A_i$ belong to the almost disjoint family $\mathfrak F$, it follows that $A_1=\cdots=A_n$, so $A_1\subseteq\bigcap\mathfrak T$, so $A_1\in\mathfrak F_0$. But this is absurd, since $D$ is disjoint from every element of $\mathfrak F_0$.

Comment: Great proof! Thanks a lot. And definitely worth to accept this. I would still be looking forward to seeing a proof for the non-maximal case. But that's just a minor.

Comment: Again, the "P.S." proof is also great. And answers my question completely. Thank you very much, again.